# Add Google Play "security metadata" without publishing an app

Tags: android, google-play, code-signing, google-play-console, android-app-signing

Recently Google has introduced [security metadata](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/google-play-security-metadata-and.html) that is added to every app uploaded into Google Play. We used to have a tampering protection that's calculating the app's signature (hash) in runtime and check if it's equal to hash that was calculated during the release. This worked fine for years, but now the GP is modifying the app's binary by adding the security metadata.

- Is there a way to disable GP security metadata at all?
- Is there a way to check (download) modified APK from the store without publishing it? It seems that apps in beta channels are not modified so this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no way to disable the Google Play security metadata.
- You can't get it without publishing an app
- APKs in alpha and beta channels are modified (or should be) but only if they were uploaded after the start date of the program (2018-06-19 12:00 UTC). However, the APK will have different metadata when it is in Beta to when it is in production.
- Hashing solutions will continue to work, but not ones which hash the whole file. Alternatives you could consider include hashing the zip entries, or hashing the classes.dex files. These methods work successfully for other developers.

Another option which works if you occasionally have online access (which I assume you do if you are checking a hash) is to use the [SafetyNet attestation API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation) to check your app, and verify the signature offline on the server. Again, many big name developers use this successfully.

Comment: Hi Nick. As you pointed out, we do hash the whole file. We were thinking about switching to hashing the DEX and crucial resource files, but that change will be non-backward compatible for us :( The hash is used not only as a DRM but also as a component for many other internal security functionalities. Could you explain a bit what kind of ZIP entries could we hash instead of the whole APK/ZIP?

Comment: None of the zip entries are changed. As the block post says, the metadata is added to the APK signing block, so each individual file is exactly as the developer sent it. To understand more see https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2 So it is only whole file hashes  of the APK that will break - a hash of anything else will be unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your questions, sorry, but posting anyway in case that helps you or anyone else in the same case: instead of checking the hash, have you considered verifying the signature of the APK? Apksig is an open source library and would allow you to achieve a similar result in a more robust way.

Comment: Hi, we also validate the app's signature, but it's not enough for our needs.